# Prevent bottom image from showing before cover image paints

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is probably very simple.

I have an image that paints and then a cover image that's gray and has a "?" mark on it. Essentially, the top image "HIDES" the bottom image until the user can "scratch off" the cover image. What's happening is, on REFRESH the images in the back (like Slot Machine images) are "flashing" giving away what could be a winning combination.

I have a three by three grid with 9 possible images.

Here's the example of what the grid is:

[Sample Grid: http://www.omnimanager.co/images/sampleGrid.png](http://www.omnimanager.co/images/sampleGrid.png)

Notice, the gray cover with "?" mark.... well when the page loads, the background image displays first for a split second and then the cover images displays giving away a possible "hint".

here's the loading code:

The loading code for the BOTTOM images:

```
var images = ['slide1.jpg', 'slide2.jpg', 'slide3.jpg',
    'slide4.jpg', 'slide5.jpg', 'slide6.jpg',
    'slide7.jpg', 'slide8.jpg', 'slide9.jpg'];

$(document).ready(function() {

    //Scratch pad randomizer
    for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {

        $('#wScratchPad3-' + i).css({'background-image': 'url(images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'});

    }
});
```

The following code is the code to load the COVER image(s):

NOTE: this code sits INSIDE the document.ready function... it's out here for clarity.

```
//Scratch off monitoring
$("#wScratchPad3-1").wScratchPad({
    cursor: 'cursors/coin.png',
    scratchMove: function(e, percent)
    {

        if (percent >= 60)
        {
            percentCmplt[0] = 100;
            this.clear();
            winner();
        } else {
            percentCmplt[0] = Math.round(percent);
        }

    },
    backImage1: $("#wScratchPad3-1").css("background-image")
});
$("#wScratchPad3-2").wScratchPad({
    cursor: 'cursors/coin.png',
    scratchMove: function(e, percent)
    {
        if (percent >= 60)
        {
            percentCmplt[1] = 100;
            this.clear();
            winner();
        } else {
            percentCmplt[1] = Math.round(percent);
        }
    },
    backImage2: $("#wScratchPad3-2").css("background-image")
});
$("#wScratchPad3-3").wScratchPad({
    cursor: 'cursors/coin.png',
    scratchMove: function(e, percent)
    {
        if (percent >= 60)
        {
            percentCmplt[2] = 100;
            this.clear();
            winner();
        } else {
            percentCmplt[2] = Math.round(percent);
        }
    },
    backImage3: $("#wScratchPad3-3").css("background-image")
});
$("#wScratchPad3-4").wScratchPad({
    cursor: 'cursors/coin.png',
    scratchMove: function(e, percent)
    {
        if (percent >= 60)
        {
            percentCmplt[3] = 100;
            this.clear();
            winner();
        } else {
            percentCmplt[3] = Math.round(percent);
        }
    },
    backImage4: $("#wScratchPad3-4").css("background-image")
});
$("#wScratchPad3-5").wScratchPad({
    cursor: 'cursors/coin.png',
    scratchMove: function(e, percent)
    {
        if (percent >= 60)
        {
            percentCmplt[4] = 100;
            this.clear();
            winner();
        } else {
            percentCmplt[4] = Math.round(percent);
        }
    },
    backImage5: $("#wScratchPad3-5").css("background-image")
});
$("#wScratchPad3-6").wScratchPad({
    cursor: 'cursors/coin.png',
    scratchMove: function(e, percent)
    {
        if (percent >= 60)
        {
            percentCmplt[5] = 100;
            this.clear();
            winner();
        } else {
            percentCmplt[5] = Math.round(percent);
        }
    },
    backImage6: $("#wScratchPad3-6").css("background-image")
});
$("#wScratchPad3-7").wScratchPad({
    cursor: 'cursors/coin.png',
    scratchMove: function(e, percent)
    {
        if (percent >= 60)
        {
            percentCmplt[6] = 100;
            this.clear();
            winner();
        } else {
            percentCmplt[6] = Math.round(percent);
        }
    },
    backImage7: $("#wScratchPad3-7").css("background-image")
});
$("#wScratchPad3-8").wScratchPad({
    cursor: 'cursors/coin.png',
    scratchMove: function(e, percent)
    {
        if (percent >= 60)
        {
            percentCmplt[7] = 100;
            this.clear();
            winner();
        } else {
            percentCmplt[7] = Math.round(percent);
        }
    },
    backImage8: $("#wScratchPad3-8").css("background-image")
});
$("#wScratchPad3-9").wScratchPad({
    cursor: 'cursors/coin.png',
    scratchMove: function(e, percent)
    {
        if (percent >= 60)
        {
            percentCmplt[8] = 100;
            this.clear();
            winner();
        } else {
            percentCmplt[8] = Math.round(percent);
        }
    },
    backImage9: $("#wScratchPad3-9").css("background-image")
});
```

In sum, I want to make the BACK IMAGES paint AFTER the COVER images.

That's pretty much it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One quick and dirty way to do this, assuming the cover and back images are the same size - make the back images BACKGROUNDs of the cover images, and don't set a width/height for your cover images.  The  elements will only receive a size once the cover images have loaded, and at that point they'll be drawn instead of their backgrounds.

Alternatively, you could set the background images to width: 0, height: 0, and add a javascript window.onload() handler to set their dimensions to auto... the onload() handler will only fire after all the images on the page have loaded.

Comment: Traversing the DOM costs, so try to cache your selectors when you can (save a copy of $('#wScratchPad3-1') to a variable instead of calling it twice).  This saves the browser from having to "find" the same element multiple times.

Comment: Also, try to keep your code DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself).  It's pretty clear you've copied and pasted the same block of code 9 times, making small changes each time... don't do that :)

[code]
$('.pads').each(function(i, pad){
  pad
    .css({'background-image': 'url(images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'})
    .wScratchPad({
      //options - i is an iterator for the loop
    });
});
[/code]

Answer (score 0):

Adding code to comments is difficult or doesn't work, so here... this should be able to replace your entire document.ready() code (untested though, may need tweaking):

```
$(function(){ //same as document.ready() but shorter
    $('.pads').each(function(i, pad){
        var settings = {
            cursor: 'cursors/coin.png',
            scratchMove: function(e, percent)
            {

                if (percent >= 60)
                {
                    percentCmplt[i] = 100;
                    this.clear();
                    winner();
                } else {
                    percentCmplt[i] = Math.round(percent);
                }

            }
        };

        settings["backImage" + (i + 1)] = pad.css("background-image");

        pad
          .css({'background-image': 'url(images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'})
          .wScratchPad(settings);
    });
});
```

Comment: This looks good... just one question. the .pads... what are you referencing here?

Comment: Will you be choosing an answer for this question?